# OpenCV android sdk error

Tags: java, opencv, android, aide-ide

I am using opencv library but javacameraview layout giving this error
**aapt:Error parsing XML:unbound prefix**
This occurs at  `<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView`

Comment: Please edit your question and add some insights about your error to make it reproducible : [How do I ask a good question ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can learn about open cv from some books which you can get from http://www.filtrlink.com and search for opencv in the search box

Comment: Please see my other answer regarding opencv in AIDE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51117126/8800831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have added the **Dependencies** of the opencv to the android

Answer (score 0):

I struggled finding a working example with a included opencv library, but then i found the github project https://github.com/hschott/Camdroid (it's not written by me). opencv 3 is included and the build is passing, one has just to strip off all unneeded parts. I had the same issue with
 aapt:Error parsing XML:unbound prefix